# Ruby - can't modify frozen string (TypeError)

Tags: ruby

Got

> ... '[]=': can't modify frozen string (TypeError)

when trying to modify what I thought was a copy of ARGV[0].

Same results for each of

```
arg = ARGV[ 0 ]
arg_cloned = ARGV[ 0 ].clone
arg_to_s = ARGV[ 0 ].to_s

arg[ 'x' ] = 'y'
arg_cloned[ 'x' ] = 'y'
arg_to_s[ 'x' ] = 'y'
```

Comment: `ARGV` comes with strings  in a frozen state `ARGV.map(&:dup)` will return an array with the same non-frozen strings.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

since google took too long to find the right answer ...

needed to do

```
arg_dup = ARGV[ 0 ].dup
```

Comment: Right. Clone copies the object's entire state, including frozen status. Dup copies the meat of the object without those other flags.

Comment: quite surprised that .to_s does the same (including frozen)!?

Comment: 64 seconds from the posting of your question, to searching Google and getting irritated to posting your answer was too long? :)

Comment: much more than that ... did lots of google searching which took ages to find right result. Then I posted this question and the answer so "stack" has it and it's easily findable now (for when I forget). Number 1 hit in google now!

Comment: In 2.1.0, `Object#dup` does not copy frozen state.

Comment: Is this specific to some Rubies? Not using `dup` doesn't raise this error on my local box but does so on Heroku. Both have the same version of Ruby.

Answer (score 25):

Since Ruby 2.3 recommended method is to [use the unary plus operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-2B-40), it will return a duplicated mutable string, if a string is frozen.

`+arg`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to concat so just needed to do use in this way

`'+'.dup.concat('123456789') # +123456789`