# FrozenError - can't modify frozen String (ruby 2.5+)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm trying to update ruby in our project to 2.5 and up, and bundler from `1.17.2` to `2.0.1`. After doing so, running our application produces the following error in multiple places:

```
FrozenError - can't modify frozen String:
```

This is a result of trying to set the timezone in a controller (`Time.zone = current_user.location.time_zone`) among other places.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug in Ruby 2.5. According to [this issue](https://github.com/mikel/mail/issues/1209), it may have been fixed in 2.5.3 or in 2.6.

Comment: Try to add the method "dup" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204945/ruby-cant-modify-frozen-string-typeerror

Comment: @moveson I don't think it's fixed. I tried 2.5.3, 2.5.5 and 2.6.2 and got the same error every time

Comment: @AndriyKondzolko Don't think that'll work for me, I need to modify the actual object, not a duplicate of it.

Comment: I just upgraded to Ruby 2.7.3 from 2.6.6 and this became an issue for me, with HUNDREDS of test errors like yours (`FrozenError: can't modify frozen String: ""`). I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Can you include the error backtrace and version of Rails you are using?

Comment: Sorry, my `FrozenError: can't modify frozen String: ""` errors were unrelated to `Time.zone=`; ultimately I used `rails test -b` to view the errors with a backtrace and it led me to discover that the error was not in my codebase but in a gem.

Comment: Could you add the full exception including backtrace to the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Time.use_zone(zone) with a block, for example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_action :set_time_zone

  def set_time_zone
    if logged_in?
      Time.use_zone(current_user.location.time_zone) { yield }
    else
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Time.html#method-c-zone-3D