# How to fix strings being frozen randomly

Tags: ruby

I'm running into an issue where my script is failing in random places with:

```
Error: can't modify frozen String: "Please use text available here - Test jira"
```

These lines caused the error:

```rb
description = "Please use text available here - #{@jira[:url]}"

unless previous_jira.nil?
  description << <<~PREVIOUSJIRACREATED
     Please close previous jira's:
      #{previous_jira}
  PREVIOUSJIRACREATED
end
```

I think it's a pretty simple line and I am not `freeze`ing it on purpose or anything like that. But can't understand why I am getting the error.

I have string interpolation all over my code, and the script started failing randomly at different places. The above code is just one example. I was able to identify a couple of high offenders and placed `begin/rescue` blocks around them, but I am afraid my code is getting ugly with the `rescue` blocks all over.

I tried searching, but I only got articles explaining what `freeze` is and how to `dup` the object.

I am on Ruby 2.7.0p0.

Comment: I don’t think that’s the problematic line. Where is the code where you _modify_ the string? Showing us just one line of code extracted from all context won’t get us any further.

Comment: I suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/q/37799296/3784008

Comment: @matt Thanks for the reply! I've added more code to the question. But that is it. I am declaring `description` there and trying to modify it in the next line based on a condition.

Comment: @anothermh Bingo! My class file is so big I forgot I have this on top of the file - `# frozen_string_literal: true`. Thank you very much for identifying the issue! ‍♂️ But I have string interpolation all over the class. Not sure why it's `freeze`ing implicitly in some places, and not in others. And that too very randomly. Could be a bug in Ruby?

Comment: lol no not a bug in Ruby. Let's not blame the underlying implementation of the language on an ill-defined problem in a single file. I recommend working on understanding how frozen strings are handled in Ruby to understand what's wrong with your specific code.

Comment: Your expanded example shows exactly the issue: when you set `description = 'foo'` that string is frozen. In the next line you attempt to modify the frozen string with `<<` which isn't going to work. If you want to do that, use for example the [unary plus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52929605/3784008) as in `description = +description << 'bar'` or string interpolation to reset the variable as in `description = "#{description}bar"`.

Comment: "`Could be a bug in Ruby?`". I'd highly recommend reading at least the  section "[Don't rush to claim that you have found a bug](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#idm368)" but the entire page is highly recommended.

Comment: @anothermh Gotcha! Totally makes sense to replace the string with new one instead of appending when I said `frozen_string_literal` is `true. For now I turned `frozen_string_literal` to `false` and it's working as normal. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for the link! It's informative. But the point I am trying to make is, I have string init and append in a lots of places in the same class file, and also in a several other class files (which also have `frozen_string_literal: true`). I don't understand why I am seeing random failures in different places each time when all could've failed once? This is what's confusing me. Hope you understand!

Comment: @scorpion35 That's exactly the point TinMan was making. You say you're confused and don't understand what's going on. So what's more likely, that Ruby has a bug, or that code that confuses you and that you don't fully understand has a bug?

Comment: Your example code doesn't duplicate the problem you describe, so how are we supposed to help fix the problem? Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. The question _must_ have the minimal code that demonstrates the problem. It's not possible to try to determine every possible scenario where your tiny snippet could go wrong without the supporting code.

Comment: @theTinMan Yes, exactly. That is the issue I am trying to describe. I had `frozen_string_literal: true` from the beginning and have a lot of string appends throughout my code. However, my script fails randomly at different string append places. My understanding is, if `frozen_string_literal: true`, it should NOT allow any type of string append anywhere in the class file. The code I posted in the question was not something I wrote like a min ago and then it started failing. I have the similar code in several other places. Confused why `frozen_string_literal: true` is failing some randoml.

Comment: I'll bet $100 that it isn't failing randomly, but is instead failing predictably according to the rules around usage of frozen strings, and that given a proper code sample and stack traces for any errors from that code all errors can be adequately explained.